# How to get previous value and compare with new value before bind value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working with real time application to show current gold market rates. I'm getting service by ajax and convert the value and displaying into tables. Currently create dynamically this table and append into div. So i can compare with table row data with currently getting value and can set price up/ down or normal color value like bellow,

```
var tableid = document.getElementById("ratetable");
for(var i=1;i<tableid.rows.length;i++) {
    selling_rate = data.Commodities.Commodity.selling_rate;
    buying_rate =  data.Commodities.Commodity.buying_rate;

    if(tableid.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML > selling_rate) {
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.color = "#FFFFFF"; //Red
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.background = "#FF0000";
    } else if(tableid.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML < selling_rate) {
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.color = "#ffffff"; //Green
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.background = "#2636f2";
    } else {
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.color = "#000000"; //black
        tableid.rows[i].cells[1].style.background = "";
    }   
    tableid.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = selling_rate;

}
```

For this i used bellow code to create table in angular js

```
<table width="480" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rate-table" id="ratetable">
                                    <tr class="table-title">
                                        <td width="297">DESCRIPTION</td>
                                        <td width="183">PRICE</td>
                                    </tr>
                                      <tr ng-repeat="commodity in commodityrate.Commodity" ng-class-odd="'oddrow'" ng-class-even="'silver'">
                                          <td width='297'>{{commodity.name}}</td>
                                          <td width='183'>{{commodity.selling_rate}}</td>
                                    </tr> 

                            </table>
```

But I need to check value (compare new value with previous value) and update color code. for this i tried like

```
ng-class="{highcolor: $scope.text>commodity.selling_rate, lowcolor: $scope.text<commodity.selling_rate, normalcolor: $scope.text==commodity.selling_rate}"
```

But this didn't work, how to do this in angular js. Is there any way to do this dynamic created value to compare by angular $watch.  Please any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I don't come up with any idea about how to store or get previous value in brackets expressions, but there is a workaround: **watch these elements' model change**.

Instead of adding a `$watch` on every single element, you can watch your commodity  list `commodityrate.Commodity` with setting `objectEquality` as true

```
scope.$watch('commodityrate.Commodity', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //iterating newValue and compare it the corresponding element in oldValue.
},
true);
```

BTW, you still need to add a new property like `priceTrend` to `Commodity` and use this to define your `ngClass`.

Since you always have to check every Commodity's price change when fetching new prices from backend, watch `commodityrate.Commodity` with `objectEquality` enabled won't lead you to worse performance.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me lot.Working well